# Hooks and webworkers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo-client

Is there a way for a webworker to use a react hook?

I am using Apollo Client to perform useLazyQuery which is a custom hook.

But the actual operation takes quite long and times out most often!

I want to run this on another thread to not disrupt the main application.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Before asking your question, please do some research and tries. So you could post here, the code you already tried. This will permit us to understand your project, then your need.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether your timeout problem would be fixed by executing the query in a webworker, the easiest way to achieve that (without considering pending/error states) would be something like this:

```
worker.js

self.addEventListener('message', async event => {
  const {apolloClient, query} = e.data;
  const result = await apolloClient.query({query});  
  self.postMessage(result);
  self.close();
});
```

```
App.jsx

const query = gql`Some query here`;

const useWebWorkerQuery = query => {
  const apolloClient = useApolloClient();
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
    worker.postMessage({apolloClient, query});
    worker.onmessage = event => setResult(event.data);
  }, []);
};

const App = () => {
  const result = useWebWorkerQuery(query);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(result) {
      // Do something once query completes
    }
  }, [result]);

  return null;
};

export default App;
```